# Lazily calling yes with IO.popen

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I have the following method:

```
def yessir
  IO.popen('yes').each do |y|
    y
  end
end

puts yessir.first
```

It calls `yes`, which is a program that writes `y` to the console for all eternity. If this code is run it never returns, which means that the `yessir`-method is not lazy. How do I fix this?

Comment: delete the keyword `return`

Comment: @UriAgassi I updated the q so your answer is out of date. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
def yessir
  IO.popen('yes').lazy.each do |y|
    y
  end
end

puts yessir.first
```